# Input a date to `datetime2` in a format different than iso

Tags: date, datetime2, datenumber

Having a date stored in a macro:

```
\def\Mydate{20-12-2017}
```

I would like to do some calculations (advance days/months) using `datetime2`. If `\Mydate` stores the date in yyyy-mm-dd I won't have issues, but having the date stored in a different style (say dd-mm-yyyy), the command `\DTMsavedate` will not recognize it and I could not issue

```
\DTMsavedate{testdate}{\MyDate}
```

I can use some string manipulations to convert the date stored in the macro to the `iso` format the `\DTMsavedate` needs, but I would prefer this conversion be made by the same `datetime2` package or a package that manipulates date strings specifying the input style. In the `\Mydate` example the user should specify the `ddmmyyyy` format and the separator in the same way as he/she decides to work with the 'mmddyyyy' format.

There is some way to input a date given as `dd-mm-yyyy` into `datetime2` to operate with it?

It would be better if the input format could be specified and the task of converting a date into a format recognized by the package is delegated to the same package.

Comment: Do you want to be able to use *both* styles of input, or are you asking how to change `datetime2` to operate on the alternative format only?  If you want to use both, then conversion with a macro would be simpler; if you want to use just the alternate, then it's not too hard to modify the `datetime2` parser.

Comment: In whatever style, @AlanMunn. I would like to have a solution on which the user could give the date in whatever style (supported by `datetime2`, and by only specifying the style used, the date could be increased by `n` days and displayed in the style the user choose. This code will be in a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-define `\DTMsavedate` like in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

\let\DTMsaved=\DTMsavedate
\def\DTMsavedate#1#2{%
   \expandafter \ifx \csname f=\DTMinformat\endcsname \relax
      \message{! \string\DTMsavedate: input format "\DTMinformat" undeclared}%
   \else \csname f=\DTMinformat\expandafter\endcsname#2&{#1}\fi
}
\def\DTMfdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname f=#1\endcsname}
\def\DTMs#1#2{\DTMsaved{#2}{#1}}
\def\DTMinformat{yyyy-mm-dd}

% input format declarations:
\DTMfdef{yyyy-mm-dd}#1-#2-#3&{\DTMs{#1-#2-#3}}  % iso input
\DTMfdef{dd-mm-yyyy}#1-#2-#3&{\DTMs{#3-#2-#1}}
\DTMfdef{yyyymmdd}#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8&{\DTMs{#1#2#3#4-#5#6-#7#8}}
\DTMfdef{ddmmyyyy}#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8&{\DTMs{#5#6#7#8-#3#4-#1#2}}
\DTMfdef{dd.mm.yyyy}#1.#2.#3&{\DTMs{#3-#2-#1}}

\begin{document}
\def\DTMinformat{yyyy-mm-dd}
\DTMsavedate{test1}{2017-12-20}

\def\DTMinformat{dd-mm-yyyy}
\DTMsavedate{test2}{20-10-2017}

\def\DTMinformat{yyyymmdd}
\DTMsavedate{test3}{20171020}

\def\DTMinformat{dd.mm.yyyy}
\DTMsavedate{test4}{21.5.2017}

Test1 is \DTMusedate{test1}

Test2 is \DTMusedate{test2}

Test3 is \DTMusedate{test3}

Test4 is \DTMusedate{test4}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The main date parser for inputting dates in `datetime2` is `\@dtm@parsedate`. This can be redefined to use `dd-mm-yyyy` input, and all other `datetime2` commands will work as before.  The display style of course is set by `datetime2` anyway.

It easy to have  `datetime2` recognize both input styles in the same document.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\newcount\myct
% Make datetime2 use either  dd-mm-yyyy input format or iso format
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{datetime2-calc}
{\def\@dtm@parsedate#1-#2-#3\@dtm@endparsedate{%
    \ifnum#1>31\relax
        \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1-#2-#3}{\@dtm@julianday}%
    \else
        \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#3-#2-#1}{\@dtm@julianday}%
    \fi
        \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\@dtm@julianday}{\@dtm@year}{\@dtm@month}{\@dtm@day}%
        \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\@dtm@julianday}{\count@}%
        \edef\@dtm@dow{\number\count@}%
}}
{\def\@dtm@parsedate#1-#2-#3\@dtm@endparsedate{%
\edef\@dtm@month{\number#2}%
\ifnum#1>31\relax
  \edef\@dtm@year{\number#1}%
  \edef\@dtm@day{\number#3}%
\else
  \edef\@dtm@day{\number#1}%
  \edef\@dtm@year{\number#3}%
\fi
  \def\@dtm@dow{-1}%
}}
\makeatother

\DTMsetstyle{ddmmyyyy} % Set output format to match

\begin{document}
\DTMsavenow{mynow}
\DTMsavedate{dec20}{20-12-2017}
\DTMsavedate{oct20}{20-10-2017}
\DTMsavedate{oct20iso}{2017-10-20}

Today is \DTMusedate{mynow}

December 20th is \DTMusedate{dec20}

October 20th is \DTMusedate{oct20}

October 20th ISO input is \DTMusedate{oct20iso}

\DTMsaveddatediff{oct20}{dec20}{\myct}
\DTMusedate{oct20} is
\ifnum\myct=0
   the same day as
\else
   \ifnum\myct<0
        \number-\myct\space day\ifnum\myct<-1s\fi\space before
    \else
        \number\myct\space day\ifnum\myct>1s\fi\space after
\fi \fi
\DTMusedate{dec20}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks! Very clever the automatic swap between year and day when the input is `iso` or `ddmmyyyy`. It should work for me in a first approximation to solve the problem or as a workaround. However, I misunderstood your question about the *both styles*: I won't need both styles at the same compilation like in your example, because cases like `mmddyyyy` will be impossible to distinguish from other formats. I wish the user has the chance to supply the date following its locale, so for example `dd-mm-yyyy`, `mm-dd-yyyy`, `dd.mm.yyyy`, iso or any format and this date being recognized by datetime2

Comment: @EmilioLazo This would require a lot more work, since the locale information is designed only for output format not input format. I guess you could  hook into the locale to make different versions of `\@dtm@parsedate`.  What you're asking for is effectively a major feature request for the package.

Comment: Understood... not easy to interpret a date displayed according to all output formats, but a the simplest cases `mm-dd-yyyy`, `dd-mm-yyyy` and `iso` with whatever separator might be implemented in the parser with a new macro to tell the parser which input style should use. Anyone interested? :-) I'll try! Thanks @AlanMunn.

Comment: @EmilioLazo Well there's enough here to do what you want. Hooking it off of the locale itself would be the most elegant, but would require a lot of delving into the localization code of `datetime2`. Creating your own input setup macro wouldn't be hard though.